# Cherrypy pass local variable between functions under Root()

Tags: python, cherrypy

Please look at the code :

```
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        self._Name = None

    def index(self):
        self._Name = getNameFromUser() 
        return mytemplate.render()
    index.exposed = True

    def foo(self):
        myName = self._Name
        //dosomething
        return mytemplate.render( showmyName( myName) )
    foo.exposed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Here is the problem:
user 1 , user 2 and user 3 come in, 
then when site wants to show the name by foo() It returns the most recent user that came into the site
I want each user see his/her name.

```
In Fact I want to have local variable per user HOW to do that ?
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set something on the server object, you are setting it for the *application* not the user.  If you want to store information on a user temporarily, use the [`sessions`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/sessions.html) interface or (if it is not information that needs to be secured / tamper-proof) in a [cookie](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/cookies.html).

Comment: All of the usual caveats apply - *never* trust user data and *always* sanitize it, even if you set it - unless it never leaves your server it can be tampered with.

Comment: Well, what I want is to have some sort of class instance for each user that call the server then I can make a variable local in the class. Is there anyway to do that ??

Comment: @user1034723 - what are you trying to accomplish that requires that the CherryPy class keep a reference to the user? In other words, why is it that you cannot get the user's information, store it in a session and then restore the user's information from the session for each request?

Comment: Well, frist of all I dont know how to do that !, secondly, what you say is that there is not a way to make something unique per user ? for example create ** f=Foo()** which is located in def Index: